# How can I confirm in-app purchase worked on a Testflight app

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I developed one app with in app purchase feature. I want to test that in-app purchase is working or not.Firstly, I used sand box tester for testing the IAP it worked perfectly but there is no conformation mail or anything so that I placed my app in testflight mode. I downloaded that app from testflight and tested from testflight also IAP work perfectly but I didn't receive any conformation. I want the conformation mail any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The testing inApp purchase, is perfect and if it works with the test users it will work properly once you release the app. Also there is one more way to test it is described here in app doc: [More Info Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase/testing_promoted_in_app_purchases)